# usleep não está funcionando no Windows

Tags: php

Estou usando `usleep` para simular internet mais lenta nos meus projetos, para assim ter uma melhor percepção das telas quando existe loads para requisições ajax por exemplo.

Usando um ambiente linux parece funcionar normal se uso:

```
usleep(2500);
```

Mas no Windows parece não ter efeito algum, o atraso não ocorre. Eu sei que o `usleep` tem alguns problemas que pode variar pra cada processador e até sei desta alternativa citada no [php.net#54572](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usleep.php#54572):

```
dl('php_w32api.dll');

$GLOBALS['win32api'] =& new win32;

// USleep alternative for Windows and PHP4:
$GLOBALS['win32api']->registerfunction("long Sleep (long dwMillisecods) From kernel32.dll");

// Now you can call the function from everywhere in your script: $GLOBALS['win32api']->Sleep(milliseconds);

for ($msec = 2000; $msec > 0; $msec = $msec - 125) {
  echo "Hi. Next one in $msec msec.\n";
  $GLOBALS['win32api']->Sleep($msec);
}
```

Mas aonde eu li os problemas são relacionados as diferenças de tempo e processador chegando a 100%, mas não encontrei sobre a função "não funcionar".

Estou usando:

- Processador: Interl Core i5 m450 (2.40 GHz)
- PHP 5.4.12 (Thread Safety)
- Arquitetura x64
- API do servidor: Apache 2.0 Handler

Será que é uma variação de processador ou da versão do PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a DOC, [usleep](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usleep.php) — Atrasa a execução em *milionésimos de segundo*, logo, `usleep(2500)` pode ser imperceptível no teste de simulação que você está fazendo. Talvez a precisão não seja 100% trabalhando-se com *milionésimos de segundo*, mas aqui `usleep(2500)` funciona corretamente.

```
echo microtime(1)
usleep(2500)
echo microtime(1)

1439005351.1457
1439005351.1487
```

---

A única referência de 'bug' relatada no ambiente Windows que encontrei foi, [Function usleep doesn't work under Windows](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29474), e na minha opinião, trata de um equívoco ao usar `usleep (500)` e esperar um atraso de *1/2 segundo*.

Comment: Realmente foi uma gafe minha, `usleep(2000000);` deveria ser o certo pra 2 segundos por exemplo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, achei que você estivesse fazendo alguma medição mais detalhada. Seria um comentário, mas não coube e virou resposta. rs

Comment: na minha ideia milionésimo era pra "mil", mas o seu comentário é a resposta certa, foi um equivoco meu, já que milionésimo se refere-se àquele que ocupa a posição de milhão em uma série. :( as vezes eu mesmo me trapaceio kkkkkk! Muito obrigado. Se quiser adicionar a explicação sobre milionésimo pra outras pessoas "confusas". Obrigado. https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/milionésimo

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, os comentários complementam as repostas, o mérito é seu :)